# How to read static checkbox in PDF file using java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to read the content of a PDF file using PDFbox. This pdf file contains some checkboxes and these checkboxes are static(i.e we can not check or uncheck the check box). When i am trying to create a object of  then it is giving **null** result.

```
PDAcroForm  acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
```

I there any other way to identify the checkbox. Below is the screenshot(I could not attach PDF file since it contains customer sensitive information)[image]

Comment: Please indicate whether that checkbox is generated as a bitmap graphics? Or a vector graphic? Or as either on wrapped in a pattern or a type 3 Font character? Or is it a character from some regular font? Or some other construct? If you don't know, I cannot help without the PDF for analysis.

Comment: If you do an ordinary text extraction with the ExtractText command line utility, what do you get? https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html#extracttext

Comment: @Tilman getText() method of PDFTextStripper class is not able to capture this tick mark.

Comment: @Tilman With ExtractText command also this tick mark is not captured it is showing as : "THE EQUIPMENT INSTALLED:
 INTRUSION  SMOKE or FIRE  TEMPERATURE"

Comment: @Sameer then it could be like mkl mentioned. The best would be to use OCR.